# Unable to iterate Database.SaveResult list

Tags: apex, batch, dml

I am doing an insert using `Database.Insert` in a batch class as follows:

```
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(clonedList, false);

for (integer i=0; i<srList.size(); i++) {

    system.debug('srList : '+i+' : '+srList[i].isSuccess());

    if(!srList[i].isSuccess()){

        errorMap.put(clonedList[i].ParentId__c,srList[i].getErrors().get(0).getStatusCode()+':'+srList[i].getErrors().get(0).getMessage());

    }

}
```

When I check the debug logs, I see the code has not entered the `srList` loop.

I know there are some errors and records not inserted, but I am not getting the `errorMap` populated.

Comment: I suggest you add `system.debug('clonedList= + clonedList)` immediately before your insert; AFAIK the only way you would get zero results is if you inserted zero objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should only find this scenario (not entering the loop) when `clonedList` is empty.

Here's my own snippet of code I tested against and had no issues.

[image: Update Case]

source code:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{new Account(), new Account(), new Account()};
Database.SaveResult[] saveResult = Database.update(accounts, false);

for(Database.SaveResult saveRes : saveResult) {
    if(!saveRes.isSuccess()) {
        for(Database.Error err : saveRes.getErrors()) {
            system.debug(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And before anyone says anything with my update, I also did the same test with insert:

[image: Insert Case]

Comment: The real repro case would be to also run it on an empty list.

Comment: I just tried it with an empty list as you suggested @AdrianLarson, but there was no debug statement. I still think NHK's variable is empty.

Comment: That's the point. That's exactly the problem the OP faced...

Comment: Got it, now i see why you edited my original post. Good looking out.